# I want to block using same email address when registering

Tags: sql, asp-classic, sql-insert

I came to a halt in doing my registration. All I want is to verify if the email address has been already used when registering.

### here's my code.

```
<%
  set MyConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  MyConn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
  MyConn.Open "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Asp\admin\reg.mdb"

  set rs=server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  dim varfname,varlname,varemail,varpass

  varfname=request.form("txtfname")
  varlname=request.form("txtlname")
  varemail=request.form("txtemail")
  varpass=request.form("txtpass")


  sql =  "SELECT user_email FROM regis"
  rs.Open sql, MyConn

  if varfname = "" then
    response.write("Please provide your first name")

  elseif varlname = "" then
    response.write("Please provide your last name")

  elseif varemail = "" then
    response.write("Please provide your email")

    do until rs.eof
      if varemail = rs.fields("user_email") then
        response.write("Email address is already used")
      end if
      rs.movenext
    loop

  elseif varpass = "" then
    response.write("Please provide your password")

  else
    register = "INSERT INTO  regis (user_first_name,user_last_name,user_email,user_password)  VALUES  ( '"&varfname&"',     '"&varlname&"', '"&varemail&"', '"&varpass&"')  "
    rs.Open register, myconn

  end if
%>
```

Comment: I think reusing emails is the least of your concern with this. You really don't want to be on this list http://plaintextoffenders.com/ do you?

Comment: Please describe the actual problem you're facing here. Does your code not do what you expect it to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: Your approach is inefficient.  You are getting all the available email addresses and then using a loop to see if an entered value is in that dataset.  A better way is to get the entered value first, and use sql to see if there is an existing record.

Comment: "Is my code possible" is not a valid question here. Of course your code is **possible**; you've written it and posted it here. Please [edit] the title so that it indicates something about the problem you're having, so that it is of some use to future readers here who find it in a search. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your if else loop makes the check against the e-mail impossible.

Change:

```
elseif varemail = "" then
response.write("Please provide your email")

do until rs.eof
if varemail = rs.fields("user_email")
response.write("Email address is already used")
rs.movenext
loop
```

To:

```
elseif varemail = "" then
  response.write("Please provide your email")

elseif Len(varemail) > 0 Then
  do until rs.eof
    if varemail = rs.fields("user_email") then
      response.write("Email address is already used")
    end if
    rs.movenext
  loop
```

**Edit:** Also you should remove the spaces in your insert function to see if that is causing an error. change it to:

```
register = "INSERT INTO regis(user_first_name,user_last_name,user_email,user_password)  VALUES( '"&varfname&"','"&varlname&"','"&varemail&"', '"&varpass&"')"
```

**Edit:** for the sake of completeness I am adding in a version of your code that uses parameterized queries and everything to help you avoid SQL injections and the like.
**Edit 2:** fixed some issues by adding second select

```
<%
  set MyConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  MyConn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
  MyConn.Open "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Asp\admin\reg.mdb"

  ' add for parameterized query '
  set objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  objCommand.ActiveConnection = MyConn


  set rs=server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  ' second record Set for inserting '
  set insertRS=server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  dim varfname,varlname,varemail,varpass

  varfname=request.form("txtfname")
  varlname=request.form("txtlname")
  varemail=request.form("txtemail")
  varpass=request.form("txtpass")

  ' change query to use a parameter '
  sql =  "SELECT user_email FROM regis WHERE user_email=?;"
  objCommand.CommandText = sql
  ' create parameter and append value '
  set objParameter = objCommand.CreateParameter("useremail", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, varemail)
  objCommand.Parameters.Append objParameter

  ' open record set '
  rs.Open objCommand, MyConn

  if varfname = "" then
    response.write("Please provide your first name")

  elseif varlname = "" then
    response.write("Please provide your last name")

  elseif varemail = "" then
    response.write("Please provide your email")

    do until rs.eof
      if varemail = rs.fields("user_email") then
        response.write("Email address is already used")
      end if
      rs.movenext
    loop

  elseif varpass = "" then
    response.write("Please provide your password")

  else
    ' create initial record set '
    ' note change ID to your primary key name '
    sql = "SELECT * FROM regis WHERE ID = 0"
    insertRS.Open sql, MyConn

    ' adds a new record to the record set '
    ' which you will insert into '
    With insertRS
      .addnew()
      ' sets each field in the record set '
      .Fields("user_first_name") = varfname
      .Fields("user_last_name") = varlname
      .Fields("user_email") = varemail
      .Fields("user_password") = varpass

      ' batch updates all changes made to this record set '
      .Resync adAffectAllChapters, adResyncUnderlyingValues
      .MarshalOptions = adMarshalModifiedOnly
      .UpdateBatch  
      ' close record set '
      set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    End With

  end if
%>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping with that loop i kinda mess that up, Your edition seems to work, giving an error message when the email has been used. But it doesn't register a new user even with a fresh email address. it seems the else part not doing it's job.

Comment: This is not the best way of doing this - you really need to follow Dan Bracuk's approach.

Comment: @Paul I am aware but opted to simply help micmat correct the code he provided.

Answer (score -4):

I think it would be better to use the `RecordCount` property of the `RecordSet` object and make sure that it's not greater than 0, but what you have should work.

I would use a dynamic SQL string like:

```
sql =  "SELECT user_email FROM regis WHERE user_email='" & varemail & "'"
```

If you do this and use the `RecordCount` property of the `RecordSet` object, your code will be much faster and tax the DB less.

Comment: This is terrible advice. You're encouraging code that allows SQL injection, and that's just wrong. If you're going to post answers for inexperienced programmers, don't teach them the wrong way from the start. Use parameterized queries - don't **EVER** concatenate SQL, particularly in a public-facing web site using user input.

Comment: He's not allowing the user to see the output.  It's not a search field.  If an SQL injection attack were used with his code it would simply error-out on the insert or update.  Or am I the onyl one who read the code?

Comment: No, he's using **user input** for the email address (which could be any text at all), and your advice is to blindly concatenate it with the SQL and execute it. That's the very definition of **SQL injection vulnerability**. If you can't see how it could be used that way, you need to Google "SQL injection" and do some studying. (Try a Google search on "Little Bobby Tables".)

Comment: @KenWhite, Did you see that I specifically added the single quotes in the string or do you think that doesn't work?  The string that I used passes the sqlmap test for vulnerabilities.  Do you think you're smarter than them?  That means that anything entered into that variable would be treated as a string and therefore not executed as a command. And anyway in this case, he uses a seperate logic loop to insert or update the DB.

Comment: I'm not discussing this; your answer (in my opinion) is wrong because it teaches poor practices rather than the proper approach (which in **all cases** is parameterized queries rather than SQL concatenation). Just because you think you can outsmart people with quote placement doesn't mean you can, and the quotes you provided are meaningless. For instance, try passing a string that contains SQL that starts with `Jones';SOME SQL STATEMENT;SELECT 'SMIT`; your attempt will happily append the leading quote, insert the SQL statements, and then append the closing quote. **Use parameterized SQL**.

Comment: Thanks for this warm response (at)Ken white, thanks for reminding to edit the title. (at)Wooble, "Please describe the actual problem you're facing here." I received an error message -Operation is not allowed when the object is open. "Does your code not do what you expect it to do?" -unfortunately no. (at)Dan Bracuk thanks for the advice "A better way is to get the entered value first, and use sql to see if there is an existing record". @Kheaney Thanks for helping with that loop i kinda mess that up, Your edition seems to work, giving an error message when the email has been used.

Comment: But it doesn't register a new user even with a fresh email address. it seems the else part not doing it's job.